# If $f$ is continuous then $ f(x)=0 $ for all $ x\in \partial \mathrm{supp}(f) $

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $ f:X \to \mathbb{R}$.
Let $ \text{supp}(f):=\overline{\{x\in X: f(x)\neq 0\}}$ be the support of $ f $. Now assume $ f $ is continuous.

This implies $\{x\in X: f(x)\neq 0\}=f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus{\{0\}})$ is open. Why is $ f(x)=0 $ for all $ x\in \partial \text{ supp
}(f) $?

Comment: Because a closed set contains it’s boundary

Comment: Yes I know this fact. The set $ \text{supp}(f) $ is closed by definition and it follows $ \partial \text{supp}(f)\subseteq \text{supp}(f) $. How does this help to get $ f(x)=0 $ for $ 
x\in \partial \text{supp}(f) $?

Comment: It was just a question and I really don't see why this question is marked and doesn't meet all Mathematics Stack Exchange guidelines. "why the question is relevant to you and our community." Because I needed some ideas. "why the question is interesting or important, etc." If you are not interested into this question then don't answer it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do it using sequences.

Take any $x\in \partial $(supp $f$).

Every neighbourhood of $x$ contains points from supp $f$ and its complement $X\setminus $supp $f$ both.  That is, more concretely, for every $n\in \mathbb N$, there exists $x_n\in X\setminus $supp $f$, such that $d(x_n,x)\lt \frac 1n$. Note that $f(x_n)=0$ for every $n$ and that $x_n\to x$ as $n\to \infty$. By continuity of $f$, it follows that $0=\lim_n f(x_n)=f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

By general properties of boundary we have $\partial A\subseteq \overline{X\backslash A}$. Let $A=f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\})$. Then $\partial A=\partial supp(f)$ because $supp(f)=\overline{A}$. But then $\partial A\subseteq \overline{X\backslash A}$ and what is $X\backslash A$? It is $f^{-1}(0)$ which is closed (by continuity of $f$). All together $\partial supp(f)\subseteq f^{-1}(0)$ which completes the proof.

Note that $X$ being metric is not relevant here. In fact the same proof works for any topological space.